# TypeDI not detecting Services from local external package

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, lerna, typedi

I have a mono repo project that consists of two (lerna built) packages `Base` and `Libs`.  I am trying to use TypeDi dependency injection and the classes marked with the `Service()` decorator from the `Libs` project are not created in the `Base` Container:

libs/example.js

```
    import { Service } from 'typedi';

    @Service()
    export class ExampleService{
        //...do stuff
    }
```

libs/index.js

```
    import { ExampleService } from './example';

    export { ExampleService };
```

base/index.js

```
    import { Container } from 'typedi';
    import { ExampleService } from 'Libs'

    //Error thrown here "Service with "MaybeConstructable<ExampleService>" identifier was not found in the container. Register it before usage via explicitly calling the "Container.set" function or using the "@Service()" decorator."
    const xmpl = Container.get(ExampleService)
```

Is there any way to inject these classes without explicitly importing all the class dependencies to the `Base` project and using `Container.set()`

Comment: I'm experiencing the same with the same setup - also got `import 'reflect-metadata';` first thing in the app and in the `libs` just in case. Any progress @Dystar?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message `ExampleService` was not registered.

The code example lacks the required `import 'reflect-metadata';` string at the entry point of your application.

Add the `reflect-metadata` as the first string to your `app/server/...` ts file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the issue for me.

Comment: @Marco, hm... if so, then, please, simplify your `libs/index.js` file. It is strange to see an import than an export. An index file can just do an export. Kind of `export * from "./example"`. Then reference this file in your `base/index.js` in this way: `import { ExampleService } from '../libs'`. It is more reliable to use relative paths. Because such a "named" path can have a lot of usage issues.